# Getting data from a given String separated by (,,-) in java

Tags: java

I am having a String like this `"5006,3030,8080-8083"`.

I want each element separately from the String:

```
5006
3030
8080
8081
8082
8083
```

Here's my code:

```
int i=0,j=0;
String delim = "[,]";
String hyphon = "[-]";
String example = "5006,3030,8080-8083";
String p[] = example.split(delim);
int len = p.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    String ps[]=p[i].split(hyphon);
    if(ps.length>1) {
        int start =  Integer.parseInt(ps[0]);
        int finish = Integer.parseInt(ps[1]);
        int diff = finish-start+1;
        for(j=0;j<diff;j++) {
            System.out.println(start+j);
        }
    } else if(ps.length==1) {
        System.out.println(ps[0]);
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution or any class that simplifies my code?

I also want the numbers in a ascending order.

Comment: 1. Split it 2. Add those numbers to sorted set<Integer>.

Comment: Looks ok. To improve your code: 1. define i,j in for cycle `(for int i=0..)`. 2. for inner iterating use `for (int j=start; j<=finish; j++)...`

Comment: He's already using it. I don't think the code can be made any better.

Comment: @lurker But then, how do you get the integers between the `-`?

Comment: @Tunaki check the results of using a `regex`, you can easily see the result with a simple online tool like this - [link](http://www.beansoftware.com/Test-Net-Regular-Expressions/Split-String.aspx)

Comment: Good enough IMO unless you *really* need to consider performance. For very large inputs, you might want to consider parsing it in a more complex way, but for most uses this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Tunaki sorry I missed that the OP was working with a range.

Comment: @Tunaki me too, sorry about that. OP, please make this a bit clearer, as it is easy to get confused if you want only the numbers or the range.

Comment: If you have huge ranges, you probably want to create an `Iterator` rather than producing the whole list all in one go. That will allow you to move sequentially through the output without generating it all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String input = "5006,3030,8080-8083";
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 String[] numbers = input.split(",");

 for (String s : numbers) {
    if (s.contains("-")) {
      String[] range = s.split("-");
      int from = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
      int to = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
      for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
         list.add(i);
      }
    } 
    else {
      list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
 }

System.out.println("in asc order");
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list.toString());

System.out.println("in desc order");
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list.toString());

}
```

My output :

```
in asc order
[3030, 5006, 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083]
in desc order
[8083, 8082, 8081, 8080, 5006, 3030]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are good to go; you can minimize the counter variables using [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/EnhancedForDemo.java) and while loop.

```
String example = "5006,3030,8080-8083";
String[] parts=example.split(",")

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(String part: parts)
{

   if(part.contains("-"))
   {

      String subParts[]=part.split("-");

      int start =  Integer.parseInt(subParts[0]);
      int finish = Integer.parseInt(subParts[1]);


       while(start <= finish)
       {
       numbers.add(start);
           System.out.println(start++);

       }
   }
   else {
        System.out.println(part);
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
    }

}

Integer[] sortedNumbers = new Integer[numbers.size()];
sortedNumbers = Arrays.sort(numbers.toArray(sortedNumbers));
```

---

**Update** (*from comment*):
Numbers are sorted now.

Comment: You didn't order the numbers.

Comment: @Jure sure I will modify my answer but his desired output is not sorted

Answer (score 2):

> I also want the numbers in a ascending order.

This adds an unexpected twist to your whole program, because once you realize that printing-as-you-go no longer works, you need to start almost from scratch.

The first thing to do is picking an appropriate representation. It appears that you represent ranges of integers, so start by defining a class for them:

```
class IntRange : Comparable<IntRange> {
    private int low, high;
    public int getLow() {return low;}
    public int getHigh() {return high;}
    public IntRange(int low, int high) {
        // Add range check to see if low <= high
        this.low = low; this.high = high;
    }
    public IntRange(int point) {low = high = point;}
    @Override
    public void print() {
        for (int i = low ; i <= high ; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(IntRange other) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use your code to split on `[,]`, then split on `[-]`, construct `IntRange`, and put it into an `ArrayList<IntRange>`. After that you can use `sort()` method to sort the ranges, and print them in the desired order.

But wait, there is more to your problem than meets the eye. Think what would happen for input like this:

```
1,5,3-7,6
```

Where should `5` and `6` be printed? It is not good to print it before or after `3-7`, so the trick is to *remove* points inside ranges.

But even that's not all: what do you do about this input?

```
1-5,3-7
```

You should print numbers 1 through 7, inclusive, but this would require *merging* two ranges. There is a good data structure for doing this efficiently. It is called a [*range tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree). If your input is expected to be large, you should consider using range tree representation.

Comment: Congratulations on actually reading the question and spotting that OP asked for them to be in order!

Comment: @chiastic-security :) :) :) If it weren't for that little twist, the whole question would be a great candidate for migration to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str = "5006,3030,8080-8083";       
      String[] array = str.split(",");
      String ans = "";        
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          if(array[i].contains("-")){
              String[] array2 = array[i].split("-");                  
              int start = Integer.parseInt(array2[0]);
              int end = Integer.parseInt(array2[array2.length - 1]);

              for(int j = start; j <= end; j++){
                  ans = ans + j + ",";                    
              }                                                   
          }
          else{
              ans = ans + array[i] + ",";
          }
      }

      System.out.print(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes all integers are positive.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testValue="5006,3030,8080-8083";

    Integer[]result=parseElements(testValue);

    for (Integer i:result){
      System.out.println(i);
    }
}

/**
 * NumberList is a string of comma-separated elements that are either integers, or a range of integers of the form a-b. 
 * @param numberList 
 * @return all the integers in the list, and in ranges in the list, in a sorted list
 */
private static Integer[] parseElements(String integerList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> integers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] csvs=integerList.split(",");
    for(String csv : csvs){
        if(csv.contains("-")){
            String[] range=csv.split("-");
            Integer left=Integer.decode(range[0]);
            Integer right=Integer.decode(range[1]);
            for(Integer i=left;i<=right;i++){
                integers.add(i);
            }
        } else {
            integers.add(Integer.decode(csv));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(integers);
    return integers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with java 8 stream api :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "5006,3030,8080-8083";
    Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
        .flatMap(el -> el.contains("-") ? rangeToStream(el) : Stream.of(Integer.valueOf(el)))
        .sorted()
        .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(e));
}

private static Stream<? extends Integer> rangeToStream(String el) {
    AtomicInteger[] bounds = Arrays.stream(el.split("-")).map(e -> new AtomicInteger(Integer.parseInt(e))).toArray(size -> new AtomicInteger[2]);
    return Arrays.stream(new Integer[bounds[1].get() - bounds[0].get() + 1]).map(e -> bounds[0].getAndIncrement());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava's functional idioms](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained) you can achive this *declaratively*, avoiding the verbose, *imperative* for-loops. First declare a tokenizing function which converts each token in the comma-delimited string into an `Iterable<Integer>`:

```
private static final Function<String, Iterable<Integer>> TOKENIZER =
    new Function<String, Iterable<Integer>>() {  

    /**
     * Converts each token (e.g. "5006" or "8060-8083") in the input string
     * into an Iterable<Integer>; either a ContiguousSet or a List with a
     * single element
     */
    @Override
    public Iterable<Integer> apply(String token) {

        if (token.contains("-")) {
            String[] range = token.trim().split("-");
            return ContiguousSet.create(
                    Range.closed(Integer.parseInt(range[0]),
                            Integer.parseInt(range[1])),
                    DiscreteDomain.integers());
        } else {
            return Arrays.asList(Integer.parseInt(token.trim()));
        }
    }
};
```

then apply the function to the input:

```
String input = "5006,3030,8080-8083";

Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(',').trimResults().split(input);

SortedSet<Integer> numbers = Sets.newTreeSet();
Iterables.addAll(numbers,
        // concat flattens the Iterable<Iterable<Integer>>
        // into an Iterable<Integer>
        Iterables.concat(Iterables.transform(tokens, TOKENIZER)));
```

As all of the logic is basically coded into the `Function`, the client code only needs to tokenize the string into an `Iterable<String>` (with [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)), apply the `Function` through [`Iterables.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29), flatten the result of the transformation using [`Iterables.concat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable%29) and finally add the resulting `Iterable<Integer>` into a `SortedSet<Integer>` which keeps the numbers in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

U can code something like this -

```
    String s="5006,3030,8080-8083";
    String s2[]=s.split(",");
    List<Integer> li= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<s2.length;i++){
        if(s2[i].contains("-")){
            li.add(i);
        }
        else{
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s2[i]));
        }
    }
    for(Integer i:li){
        String str=s2[i];
        String strArr[]=str.split("-");
        for(int  j=Integer.parseInt(strArr[0]);j<=Integer.parseInt(strArr[1]);j++){
            numbers.add(j);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    for(Integer k:numbers){
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       String example = "5006,3030,8080-8083";
       String[] splitString = example.split(",");
       List<Integer> soretedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
       for(String str : splitString)
       {
           String[] split2 = str.split("-");
           if(split2.length == 1)
           {
               soretedNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
           }
           else
           {
               int num1 = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
               int num2 = Integer.parseInt(split2[1]);
               for(int i = num1;i <= num2; i++)
               {
                   soretedNumbers.add(i);
               }
           }
       }
       Collections.sort(soretedNumbers);
       for(int i : soretedNumbers)
       {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
    }
```

Comment: ...which is *not* the output he desires. It's not stated explicitly but from the example (desired) output it's clear a hyphen means range.

Comment: Fixed the code, so that now gives out correct output.